# Gaussian processes with categorical input

Tags: regression, machine-learning, categorical-data, gaussian-process, categorical-encoding

Is there a standard way of applying Gaussian processes to regression problems with categorical input? Are they standard kernels that one should apply to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward but **potentially inefficient** way to handle categorical input in gaussian process is to represent the categorical variables as one-hot encoding. For example, an input with $k$ categories can be represented with a one-hot vector of length $k$ such that only one element of the vector is set to 1 representing the category active for that input. One can use any standard kernel like squared exponential/hamming etc. on top of this encoding.

Answer (score 1):

A alternative solution to transforming the data inputs is to let the Gaussian Process (GP) model directly handle the categorical inputs. The model kernel can be combined as a sum of a categorical kernel and a regular kernel of the form:

```
K((x1, c1), (x2, c2)) =

K_cont_1(x1, x2) + K_cat_1(c1, c2) + K_cont_2(x1, x2) * K_cat_2(c1,c2)
```

A readily available implementation can be found in BoTorch, a Bayesian Optimization package built on PyTorch. An example use of such a kernel:

```
import torch
from botorch.models import MixedSingleTaskGP

train_X = torch.cat([torch.rand(20, 2), torch.randint(3, (20, 1))], dim=-1)
train_Y = torch.sin(train_X[..., :-1]).sum(dim=1, keepdim=True)
model = MixedSingleTaskGP(train_X, train_Y, cat_dims=[-1])
```

The link to the BoTorch MixedSingleTaskGP kernel docs page can be found [here](https://botorch.org/api/models.html#botorch.models.gp_regression_mixed.MixedSingleTaskGP).